# Subversion (SVN) and static libraries (.a files) compatibility?

Tags: iphone, svn, xcode, ios, commit

I can't add .a files (static libraries) into my repository. Why?

Is there a way to "force" SVN to accept them (at least as static files...)?

Comment: .a files are static libraries, not frameworks. Just FYI.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `svn:ignore` property contains a list of file patterns which certain Subversion operations will ignore.

Also do you have a configuration file that global-ignores. It is a list of whitespace-delimited globs which describe the names of files and directories

The `svn status`, `svn add`, and `svn import` commands also ignore files that match the list.

To override for a certain instance, use the `--no-ignore` command-line flag:

```
>>>>svn help add
usage: add PATH...

Valid options:
  --targets ARG            : pass contents of file ARG as additional args
  -N [--non-recursive]     : obsolete; try --depth=files or --depth=immediates
  --depth ARG              : limit operation by depth ARG ('empty', 'files',
                            'immediates', or 'infinity')
  -q [--quiet]             : print nothing, or only summary information
  --force                  : force operation to run
  --no-ignore              : disregard default and svn:ignore property ignores
  --auto-props             : enable automatic properties
  --no-auto-props          : disable automatic properties
```

Comment: If I understood correctly I need to edit ignore config list OR add --no-ignore to my commands. Can you confirm ? Thanks you !

Answer (score 6):

Make sure your issue is caused by the SVN ignore configuration. With *`svn status'* your '*.a' file will be missing, while *'svn status --no-ignore'* shall display it with a question mark in front.

Open the Subversion configuration file in your home directory:

```
~/.subversion/config
```

Search for the 'global-ignores' section:

```
global-ignores = *.o *.lo *.la *.al .libs *.so *.so.[0-9]* *.a *.pyc *.pyo *.rej *~ #*# .#* .*.swp .DS_Store
```

Remove ***.a** from the list of ignored files.

Comment: i would suggest to do a specific override while adding / rather than remove from this.