# SVN not considering .a library file for commit

Tags: svn

I have an external library which i need to add to my existing project.

The steps says to add the library to the project folder and Copy items into Destination group's folder and select Target. (Steps we normally perform to add a file)

But, while commiting, the SVN selectes the .h file and not the library(.a) file.

Please help.

Comment: I tried searching for answers and they said to manually add it to svn.
Is there any other way ? My concern is why is it not showing in the source control window ?

Comment: What's the client are you using? Are you doing it over command line?

Comment: please see [Subversion (SVN) and static libraries (.a files) compatibility?][1], or [SVN won't import *.a library][2]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3724817/subversion-svn-and-static-libraries-a-files-compatibility
  [2]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2394363/svn-wont-import-a-library

Comment: the second link worked but as i said earlier, I had to add it manually via command line

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to add static files again.You can use `svn add` command to add static files in svn. Then again commit the code.

Update : In XCode you can right click on .a file then `Source Control--> Add.` Then it will show added(A) status. Then commit the code from the Xcode.

Comment: I want to know is there any way by which I can add a file which is included in global-ignores (*.a) via xcode source control and not command line code : svn add file-name.a --no-ignore

Comment: It wasn't showing Add option but it was showing Update selected file !

Comment: Auk...then update it.I think your .a files are already in svn.

Comment: Actually the problem was file-types with .a were in ignore list so add option wasn't visible and also on commiting, we could not see those files to add to the commit.

Comment: This is not working in xcode6.1, Add button is disabled